# Debug LESS with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: node.js, less, google-chrome-devtools

My directory structure is as follows:

```
    css/style.css
        style.css.map
    less/style.less

index.html
```

I have created a simple index.html file as follows:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='box'></div>
</body>
```

The style.less as follows:

```
@bgcolor: green;

#box {
width: 200px;
height:200px;
background: @bgcolor;
}
```

Inside the css folder is the style.css file compiled from style.less to style.css and style.css.map using the command below on node.js command prompt:

```
lessc less/style.less > css/style.css --source-map=css/style.css.map --source-map-basepath=css
```

Then I installed less middleware:

```
 npm install less-middleware
```

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot debug less directly on Chrome since I have already Enable CSS source maps on Chrome Dev Tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chrome developer tools will not reflect .less files if the source map url at the end of the .css file is not valid

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=css/style.css.map */
```

instead should be

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

assuming the style.css.map is in the same directory as the style.css file.

Also, confirming that the url in the .css.map file is valid is also a factor to take care of!

```
{"version":3,"sources":["../less/style.less"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;EAIA,gBAAA;;AAJA,GAKA;EACA,UAAA;EACA,eAAA;;AAPA,GASA;EACA,YAAA;EACA,eAAA;;AAXA,GAaA;EACA,WAAA;EACA,eAAA;;AAIA;EAKA,mBAAA;;AALA,GAOA;EACA,aAAA;EACA,eAAA;;AATA,GAWA;EACA,aAAA;EACA,eAAA","file":"..\\undefined"}
```

Hope someone will find this helpful.